# VM gets IP from DHCP, but can't ping router. Bridged mode and Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, bridge

Host: Windows 7 64
Guest: Ubuntu 12.04

I'm using two different wireless network. One at work and one at home.

At work, VM gets IP, can connect to internet. Everything is OK.

At home, VM gets IP, router shows that new client get IP from DHCP, but I can't ping anything from that VM, even router that gave me the IP address.

NAT is working properly. Everything in bridged mode.

Wireless supports bridged mode, because in one network it's working and in the other one it's not. Any ideas?